# How to scale an app architecture with a nextjs app?

Tags: server, architecture, next.js, hosting

Let's say I have the following app (just a stupid example) https://tenant-eight.vercel.app

In words: A customer can see a business name and the address. He can leave a like, that is stored in a MySQL database. The app will send a email in the background to the business owner.

I want to sell that app to clients (b2b), so that they can collect votes on their own.

Let's say I have 100 clients. I would store the company configuration (database api url, company name, address...) in an .env file. Then I would build 100 apps. I need 100 domains, 100 web spaces, 100 databases and so on.... How can I make my life easier?

What is the best approach to realise that with less scaling issues, update maintenance, and so on? (each customer will always have the same latest code - no customer specific features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a method is just selling your apps source code and relax. Don't want it to get stolen? Two ways (both are sh#tty in an aspect but.. welcome to selling closed source things :p)

- Obfuscate the code, which will make it much slower, but not a single soul will understand it unless they are a real tech-savvy person. Clients may also feel less secure.
- Make a licensing system with a private npm project, and give out license codes to activate the website (no source code will be given)